# Scatterplots of data.frame or matrix

Tags: r

Again the same problem with matrices/dataframes and everything...
This time I try to do the scatterplot. I was pretty sure that I will be able to do it but unfortunately same problem as always apperead.

That's my data:

```
id  cond    S1.pre  S2.pre  S1.post S2.post V1.pre  V2.pre  V1.post V2.post
  1 aer       21    31        25    35         7     1        19     4
  2 aer       15    26        21    29        13    11        16    14
  3 aer       18    27        23    31         8     2         3     3
  4 aer       17    31        18    39        13    11        15    14
  5 aer       15    26        16    29        26    15        32    20
```

Used that function to read the txt file:

```
data <- read.table("Stats1.13.HW.03.txt", header=T)

> class("data")
[1] "character"
```

^ strange ?

Tried to plot it:

```
plot(data2$S1.pre~data2$S2.pre~data2$V1.pre~data2$V2.pre, col="green")

Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : 
object is not a matrix
```

Okey, that's not problem. Let me make a matrix!

```
data <- as.matrix(data)
```

Suprise ?

> plot(data$S1.pre~data$S2.pre~data$V1.pre~data$V2.pre, col="green")

```
Error in data$V2.pre : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

How to solve my problems with matrices/atomic vectors/numeric etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `class("data")` means 'give me the class of "data" string' and it is as expected `character`. You should use `class(data)` instead.

There is no `data2` in your code so it is not clear what is inside this object. Let's assume we work with `data`.

You try to plot formula like this `data$S1.pre ~ data$S2.pre ~ data$V1.pre ~ data$V2.pre` and it is not even close to a valid formula.

If you want to create multiple scatterplots you can use `pairs`

```
pairs(~data$S1.pre + data$S2.pre + data$V1.pre + data$V2.pre)
```

**EDIT**

If you have matrix you cannot use `$` notation to access columns, but you can use syntax like below:

```
data[, V1.pre]
```

You should also remember that all fields in the matrix have to be the same type so in your case all values will be converted to characters:

```
> apply(as.matrix(data[1,]), 2, class)
     id        cond      S1.pre      S2.pre     S1.post     S2.post 
"character" "character" "character" "character" "character" "character" 
V1.pre      V2.pre     V1.post     V2.post 
"character" "character" "character" "character"
```

If you want numerics you should omit `cond` column:

```
> data.matrix <- (data[, -2])
> apply(data.matrix, 2, class)
   id    S1.pre    S2.pre   S1.post   S2.post    V1.pre    V2.pre   V1.post 
"integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" 
V2.post 
"integer"
```

Comment: Okey, so now I understand that I should use "" if I work on loaded data set (not specific coulmns). This data2 is my mistake because I tried to load the data in a different way and I named it data2. Anyway, how should the plot formula looks like.. I took this code from online course... Thx for -2 anyway. :0

Comment: I'm not sure what you trying to achieve in your code, but my guess you should use `pairs`. You can check my answer for details.